# DeSerialize JSON into C# Object: How to Handle Missing properties

Tags: c#, json

I have a problem, my JSON object does not contain all the properties which are available in C# object (DataMember).

Is there any way I can ignore missing properties while deserializing JSON

```
/// <summary>
        /// Deserializes a stream that contains a json text into an object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the object to be deserialized into.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="stream">The stream that contains the json text representation of the object.</param>
        /// <returns>A deserialized object.</returns>
        public static T DeserializeJson<T>(Stream stream) where T : class 
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings();
            settings.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true;

            DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T), settings);
            return jsonSerializer.ReadObject(stream) as T;
        }
```

Comment: That depends which library you are using to deserialize your JSON.

Comment: usually there are attributes that you can set to the c# property that will tell the serializer not to serialize this property.

Comment: here is my code, please see the original message.

Comment: What actual problems are you having? When I deserialize JSON with missing properties using `DataContractJsonSerializer`, I simply get the default value for the missing field's type.

Comment: In my case, the return object is Null

Comment: Edit your question to ahow an example of the JSON you are trying to deserialize, as well as the class(es) that you are trying to deserialize to.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `IsRequired` property for `DataMemberAttribute`.
If you set it to `false`, deserialisation won't throw exception if this member is missing in your json.

```
    [DataMember( IsRequired = false )]
    public bool ManualSessionClose { get; set; }
```